# tcpdump – rotate capture files using -G, -W and -C

Tags: linux, macos, unix, tcpdump

I'm looking to be able to capture a rotating tcpdump output which captures 30 minutes worth of data, into 48 files, cyclically.

[The man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tcpdump.1.html) implies this should be possible, but my testing doesn't seem to produce the result I'm looking for:

> **`-W`**
>
>     Used  in  conjunction  with the
>     **`-C`**
>     option, this will limit the
>       number of files created to the  specified  number,  and  begin
>       overwriting  files from the beginning, thus creating a 'rotating' buffer. 
>       In addition, it will name the files with  enough
>       leading  0s  to  support the maximum number of files, allowing
>       them to sort correctly.
>
> Used in conjunction with the **`-G`** option, this  will  limit  the
>   number  of  rotated  dump files that get created, exiting with
>   status 0 when reaching the limit.  If used with **`-C`** as well, the
>   behavior will result in cyclical files per timeslice.

I'm running this on OS X 10.9.5/10.10.3 clients. Here's the test command; it just exits after the 3rd file:

```
tcpdump -i en0 -w /var/tmp/trace-%Y-%M-%d_%H.%M.%S.pcap -W 3 -G 3 -C -K -n
```

Comment: pls see my answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because you wrote `-W 3` instead of `-W 48`. There are, however, other errors in your command.

The option `-G` means:

> `-G rotate_seconds`
>
> If specified, rotates the dump file specified with the **`-w`** option every *rotate_seconds* seconds.  Savefiles will have the name specified by **`-w`** which should include a time format as defined by strftime(3). 
>   If no time format is specified, each new file will overwrite the previous.
>
> If used in conjunction with the **`-C`** option, filenames will take the form of '*file*<count>'.

Since you wrote `-G 3`, you will be rotating this every 3 seconds, while you stated

> ...which captures 30 minutes worth of data

Also, the naming scheme is wrong: from the above,

> If used in conjunction with the **`-C`** option, filenames will take the form of '*file*<count>'.

Thus there is no point in specifying the time format for the name.

Further, the `-C` option has no argument, while,
according to [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump), it should:

> tcpdump [ **-AdDefIKlLnNOpqRStuUvxX** ] [ **-B** *buffer_size* ] [ **-c** *count* ]
>   [ **-C** *file_size* ] [ **-G** *rotate_seconds* ] [ **-F** *file* ]
>   [ **-I** *interface* ] [ **-m** *module* ] [ **-M** *secret* ]
>   [ **-r** *file* ] [ **-s** *snaplen* ] [ **-T** *type* ] [ **-w** *file* ]
>   [ **-W** *filecount* ]
>   [ **-E** *spi@ipaddr algo:secret,...* ]
>   [ **-y** *datalinktype* ] [ **-z** *postrotate-command* ] [ **-Z** *user* ] [ *expression* ]

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) states:

> **`-C`**
>
> Before writing a raw packet to a savefile, check whether the file is currently larger than *file_size* and, if so, close the current savefile and open a new one.  Savefiles after the first savefile will have the name specified with the **`-w`** flag, with a number after it, starting at 1 and continuing upward. 
>   The units of *file_size* are millions of bytes (1,000,000 bytes, not 1,048,576 bytes).

So you should specify `-C 100` in order to produce 100 MB files.

In the end, your command should be:

```
tcpdump -i en0 -w /var/tmp/trace -W 48 -G 1800 -C 100 -K -n
```

This will rotate files (of names trace1, trace2, ...) cyclically, with period 48, either every 1800 seconds (=30 minutes) or every 100 MB, whichever comes first.

Comment: The in the end answer is missing the condition `If no time format is specified, each new file will overwrite the previous.` (I have updated the answer.)

Comment: @okwap, when you edited the answer (to add -%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S), you broke the cyclical part of using -G, -C, and -W together.  The original answer using just /var/tmp/trace for the -w filename was correct and generated the intended cyclic outputs as described ( trace1,trace2,...).  When using -G, -C, and -W together, you can't use the strftime format in the filename and still get the cyclic outputs.  With your edit, tcpdump will just continue writing out files non-cyclically because the filenames never repeat.

Comment: @BillMenees Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I have **undone** okwap's edit.

Comment: Just like Swinster in the comment below, I note that this answer does not produce the expected behavior.

Using -w -W -C and -G in conjunction causes the same file to be overwritten again and again. It does *not* cause a number of files to be created equal to -W <n> as one would expect.

Comment: My `-G` command stops working after the X seconds specified. After debugging, I found out that this command will also need `-Z username` to avoid permission error

Answer (score 10):

Expanding upon [flabdablet’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/904786/150988#1207534)
(changing `-G 1800` to `-G 300` –
rotation every five minutes –
just for testing purposes),

```
tcpdump -i en0 -w /var/tmp/trace-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%s -W 3 -G 300
```

will give you `%m=month`, `%d=day of month`, `%H=hour of day`, `%M=minute of day`, `%S=second of day`, `%s=millisecond of day`,
resulting in

```
/var/temp/trace-03-02-08-30-56-1520002568
/var/temp/trace-03-02-08-35-56-1520002568
/var/temp/trace-03-02-08-40-56-1520002568
```

Very useful for organizing traces for those pesky intermittent problems. 
Also, if you're not root, you may want to `sudo` and of course make it a nohup:

```
sudo bash -c "nohup tcpdump -i en0 -w /var/tmp/trace-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%s -W 3 -G 300 &"
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me that all you need is

```
tcpdump -i en0 -G 1800 -w /var/tmp/trace-%H-%M.pcap
```

The strftime format specifier that -G expects in the -w filename doesn't have to represent a complete date and time. With just %H and %M in there, and a rotate time of exactly half an hour, any given invocation of tcpdump will only ever generate two different %M values half an hour apart, and yesterday's trace files will get overwritten when the same hour and minute numbers roll around again.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I couldn't get @MariusMatutiae answer to work as expected. If the time became the limiting factor and without the addition of the time format to the file name, then the current pcap file is simply overwritten.

For example, try:

```
tcpdump -i en0 -w /var/tmp/trace -W 10 -G 5 -C 1
```

All you end up with is `trace.pcap0` being written over and over.

As it suggested in the comment, if you add the time formatting to the file name, then you simply end up with and every growing list of files.

Therefore, I had to stick with simple size limited files:

```
tcpdump -i en0 -w /var/tmp/trace -W 48 -C 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it doesn't seem to work as [MariusMatutiae's](https://superuser.com/a/929011/851430) answer says.

```
tcpdump ...{other options}... -w httpdebug.pcap -W 48 -G 1800 -C 100
```

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 tcpdump tcpdump  100007441 Mar 17 17:57 httpdebug.pcap00
-rw-r--r--. 1 tcpdump tcpdump   46895104 Mar 17 18:02 httpdebug.pcap01
-rw-r--r--. 1 tcpdump tcpdump   93091143 Mar 17 17:47 httpdebug.pcap02
-rw-r--r--. 1 tcpdump tcpdump    5372072 Mar 17 16:17 httpdebug.pcap03
```

It looks to me like it might be capturing as many `-C 100`MB files as possible in a 30 minute period because `httpdebug.pcap03` has the earliest timestamp and it's a lot smaller than 100MB, so it seems like it was cut at a 30 minute mark. Once it hits 30 mins, it seems to jump back to `httpdebug.pcap00` and increment the number as it hits 100MB. This means that if you have a lot of requests in a 30 minute period, you get to very high httpdebug.pcapXX numbers. If you never reach that many requests in a period anymore, those high httpdebug.pcapXX numbers won't ever get overwritten.

So I'm thinking **cyclical files per timeslice** means that the timeslice is `-G 1800` and it will cycle every `-G 1800` and increment every `-C 100`.

I'm not sure if `-W 48` affects it, but perhaps if you get to `httpdebug.pcap47` (count starts at 0`, it will stop capturing packets.

---

Somewhat recently, there was a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/695) opened about the confusing wording. They did not change the implementation, but they tried to make the documentation a little bit clearer.

The [proposed changes](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/pull/722) were merged in on [Jan 28, 2019](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/pull/722#event-2102485055).

As of today, March 17, 2019, here is the current documentation:

[`-C`](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/362304dd6832fa5a966156b4d0746e6e0a4d1edc/tcpdump.1.in#L245-L253):

```
.BI \-C " file_size"
Before writing a raw packet to a savefile, check whether the file is
currently larger than \fIfile_size\fP and, if so, close the current
savefile and open a new one.  Savefiles after the first savefile will
have the name specified with the
.B \-w
flag, with a number after it, starting at 1 and continuing upward.
The units of \fIfile_size\fP are millions of bytes (1,000,000 bytes,
not 1,048,576 bytes).
```

[`-G`](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/362304dd6832fa5a966156b4d0746e6e0a4d1edc/tcpdump.1.in#L355-L370):

```
.BI \-G " rotate_seconds"
If specified, rotates the dump file specified with the
.B \-w
option every \fIrotate_seconds\fP seconds.
Savefiles will have the name specified by
.B \-w
which should include a time format as defined by
.BR strftime (3).
If no time format is specified, each new file will overwrite the previous.
Whenever a generated filename is not unique, tcpdump will overwrite the
preexisting data; providing a time specification that is coarser than the
capture period is therefore not advised.
.IP
If used in conjunction with the
.B \-C
option, filenames will take the form of `\fIfile\fP<count>'.
```

[`-W`](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/362304dd6832fa5a966156b4d0746e6e0a4d1edc/tcpdump.1.in#L794-L815):

```
.B \-W
Used in conjunction with the
.B \-C
option, this will limit the number
of files created to the specified number, and begin overwriting files
from the beginning, thus creating a 'rotating' buffer.
In addition, it will name
the files with enough leading 0s to support the maximum number of
files, allowing them to sort correctly.
.IP
Used in conjunction with the
.B \-G
option, this will limit the number of rotated dump files that get
created, exiting with status 0 when reaching the limit.
.IP
If used in conjunction with both
.B \-C
and
.B \-G,
the
.B \-W
option will currently be ignored, and will only affect the file name.
```

I still think it's a little confusing, but I guess the difference from my conclusion above, is that it says `-W` when used with `-C -G` does not affect anything but the file name.

In general, `-W` is used for limiting the number of files. So don't use it if you want to capture indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

tcpdump -i en0 -W 5 -C 2 -w capturedfile

this created the rotated buffer of 5 of 2MB from capturedfile0 to capturedfile5.

-rw-r--r--  1 lakshitha    1.9M Jun 26 23:27 capturedfile0
-rw-r--r--  1 lakshitha    347K Jun 26 23:28 capturedfile1
-rw-r--r--  1 lakshitha    1.9M Jun 26 23:26 capturedfile2
-rw-r--r--  1 lakshitha    1.9M Jun 26 23:27 capturedfile3
-rw-r--r--  1 lakshitha    1.9M Jun 26 23:27 capturedfile4